# Python Requests: 403 Error on Glassdoor.com

Tags: python, python-requests, web-crawler, http-status-code-403

I'm trying to access company profiles on Glassdoor using requests, but the site keeps returning a 403 error. I used the same code a few days ago without any issues, so I'm not sure what the problem is. I have already tried adding headers, but that didn't work either. Interestingly, the Python request returns the following:

> Sorry, we had some trouble processing your request. Most of the time, this problem can be fixed by reloading the page. Click <a class="reload" href=""here</a to reload. If this problem persists, it may be because there's an issue with our site right now.

However, when I visit the same site on my normal browser, everything loads properly. Code is below:

```
import requests
AAPL = "https://www.glassdoor.com/Reviews/Apple-Reviews-E1138.htm"
    
headers = {"User-Agent": foo, 
           "referer": "https://www.google.com/"}

page = requests.get(AAPL, headers=headers)
```

When I try accessing websites other than Glassdoor, there are no issues, so I suspect the issue lies with Glassdoor in particular. However, that doesn't explain why the site has no problem loading when I access it using my normal browser.

Edit:

Evidently it is against Glassdoor's Terms of Service to make requests in the way described above. Glassdoor's API is also restricted, so would there be any alternative ways to reference the site? All I'm trying to do is extract review data (rating and date) for personal use.

Comment: What you are trying to do violates [their TOS](https://www.glassdoor.com/about/terms.htm) They probably are detecting your request as a "bot" or w/e and thus sending you a 403. If we would help you to circumvent their anti-bot-or-whatever detection, we would help you to violate their TOS, so do not expect help here.

Comment: normal browser sends more information - not only two headers. It may also run JavaScript which can also add information. `requests` can't run JavaScript